# vector regression in R

Tags: r, vector, regression

I would like to do a regression in R

The formula is y_t = alpha +beta* x_t-1 & x_t = theta + rho * x_t-1.
Since I would like to estimate the covariance matrix of the error. I do not know how to run regression for both equation together. Thank you.

I tried

```
lm(c(y[2:756],x[2:756])~c(x[1:755],x[1:755]),data=data1)
```

756 is the length of vector, it does not work.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? One of the downvote reasons for this site is "*This question does not show any research effort*" - you are expected to make an attempt first.

Answer (score 1):

Your example looks like you are trying to fit an autoregressive model with `lm`. Try autoregressive models instead. For multivariate autoregressive models I suggest using the `MTS` package. Something like the following should work:

```
require("MTS")
VAR(data.frame(x=x, y=y))
```

For more detail, check out `?VAR`. You may also want to have a look at the [time series task view on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html).